# How do you prove that a recursive sequence is increasing/decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the two recursively-defined following sequences:

$u_0 = a$, $v_0 = b > a$, $u_{n+1} = \sqrt{u_nv_n}$, $v_{n+1} = \frac{u_n+v_n}2$.

I want to show that $u_n$ is increasing and $v_n$ is decreasing.

I was thinking that I should show it recursively. First starting off with $u_n$, we can say that $u_{1} = \sqrt{u_0v_0} = \sqrt{ab} \ge \sqrt{a^2}$, since $b>a$.

Now, I have to show that it's true for any $n$. I couldn't get anywhere from here. Am I doing this right, or is there a better way? Thanks.

---

The possible duplicate is indeed the almost same question, but OP states that he/she has already solved it, and only asks about the another part of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic-geometric mean convergence proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021569/arithmetic-geometric-mean-convergence-proof)

Comment: This accepted answer in the linked post responds to the question in the title, see its last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

First observe that for any $n$, one has  $u_n<v_n$ (use the *AM-GM inequality*).

Supposing $b>a>0$, you easily  prove $0<u_n<v_n$. So all you have to prove is

1. $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}>1$,
2. $\dfrac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}<1$.

Comment: @MarkViola: I didn't do all the job! ;o)

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your reply. However, I don't understand why it is that we want to prove $2.$ instead of simply proving that \frac{u_{n+1}}u_n$ < 1? Wouldn't that be all that's necessary to show that it's decreasing? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you did a good job at helping without completely giving it away.

Comment: $v_n$ is *decreasing*. It means that for all $n$, $u_n<u_{n+1}$ and $v_n>v_{n+1}$. Here, as everyone is positive, you also can compare the ratios to $1$, and  it happens it's slightly  simpler.

Comment: @MarkViola: Thanks for your kind appreciation! That's in general what I try to do (not always easy!).

Comment: @Bernard My apologies, I meant to write $v_n$. In that case, why did you write $\frac{v_n+1}{vu_n}$ instead of $\frac{v_n+1}{u_n}$?

Comment: A typo (fixed). Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: @Bernard Ah good! I was freaking out that there was yet another thing I didn't understand. Two quick  follow-up question, if you'd be so kind, and I'll stop pestering you: we have to know that $a$ and $b$ are positive so that the AM-GM inequality stands, right? Also, why is the inequality $0<u_n<v_n$ of any importance when showing that $u_n$ is increasing and $v_n$ is decreasing? Thanks.

Comment: You're not pestering at all! The behaviour of inequalities w.r.t. multiplication or division is more complex if the quantities are not positive, or worse, if you do not know their signs. Anyway, if it's not positive,  even the definition of $u_{n+1}$ may fail.

Comment: @Bernard I see. So to use 1. and 2. you need to show that the sequences are positive, and to show that, you need to show that $a$ and $b$ are positive? Whether $u < v$ or vice versa is inconsequential, right?

Comment: As far as I know, this exercise  requires $a, b>0$. Both sequences converge to the same limit, called the *arithmetico-geometric mean* of $a$ and $b$. It was discovered by Legendre and Gauß (independently) and it is linked to the computation of *elliptic integrals*.

Comment: @Bernard I have heard some of those words before, haha. Anyway, thank you very much for the help, it's much appreciated. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Your inductive hypothesis is $\color{red}{v_n > u_n}$ then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{n+1}=\sqrt{u_n \color{red}{v_n}} > \sqrt{u_n \color{red}{u_n}} =u_n
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
v_{n+1}=\frac{\color{red}{u_n} +v_n}{2} < \frac{\color{red}{v_n}+ v_n}{2} =v_n.
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally by AM-GM $v_{n+1} > u_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apologies if I'm being dense, but I don't understand hwo this shows that $u$ is increasing and $v$ is decreasing. I would have thought that the conclusion we want to reach is that $u_n \ge u_{n+1}$, and the opposite for $v_n$. What am I missing?

Comment: The sequence $u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_n,u_{n+1},\cdots$ is increasing so $u_{n+1} > u_{n}$ for each $n$. i.e. the next term is bigger than the previous.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, meant to write it the other way around. Either way, I'm not understanding how the answer proves this, could you explain it to me?